# $k$-structure on $K$-schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I'm reading A. Borel's "Linear Algebraic Groups".
At an early point in the book, the author establishes the following concepts:
(Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field, and $k$ a subfield of $K$)

- **$K$-space**: a topological space $X$ along with a sheaf $O$ of $K$-algebras on $X$ such that the stalks are local rings
- **affine $K$-scheme**: a $K$-space of the form Spec$_K(A)$;
  (Spec$_K(A)$ denotes all the *maximal* ideals of a $K$-algebra $A$)
- **$K$-scheme**: a $K$-space which is locally isomorphic to an affine $K$-scheme

He then proceeds to introduce the concept of a $k$-structure on a $K$-scheme $(X, O)$, which consists of the following:

a) a $k$-topology on X (which is weaker than the original topology on $X$);
 b) a $k$-structure on each of the $O(U)$, where $U$ is $k$-open.

The question is: what does a "$k$-topology on $X$" mean, and how do we define one? Any examples are also welcome :)

Comment: Borel's book is a little old and I think he makes the identification between the $k$-points of $X$ and $X$ itself as a scheme (which was common in Weil's style of algebraic geometry). I would suggest you to study more modern books. This equivalence that I said before is written in the first chapter of Wedhorn and Görtz book (and holds for your $K$ algebraically closed). There are several ways of getting a $k$ scheme from a $K$ scheme. It could be done by Weil restriction or by just composing $X \rightarrow Spec (K)$ with $Spec (K) \rightarrow Spec (k)$.

Comment: In this case, I think he just means the second construction that I said. So in this case, he get the structure of a $k$ algebra on $O(U)$ by composing $k \hookrightarrow K \rightarrow O (U)$ and locally for $U = Spec_K (A)$ he consider $A$ as a $k$-algebra ($k \hookrightarrow K \rightarrow A$) and, then, the new topology will be on $U$ defined by  $U= Spec_k (A) $.